# Many Vectors, find closest 4 to object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have array of Vector3:

```
public Vector3[] positions;
```

I have object and position of this object stored in Vector3 variable.

I have second Vector3 array:

```
public Vector3[] four;
```

I need to find from array **positions** 4 closest vectors to the object and put them to the array **four** .

I'm thinking how to do it for few hours but I really don't know how. Please give me some ideas (Please in C#).

Comment: So what *can* you do? Can you calculate the distance between two positions? Can you create anonymous objects of a vector and a distance? Can you sort a list by distance? Can you pick the first four?

Answer (score 4):

This should work. It computes all the distances between myObject and all positions and stores them together with the position index.

It then sorts this results based on the distance.

Finally it takes the first 4 results and uses the stored index to get the correct position.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Distance
{
   public float distance;
   public int index;

   public Distance( float distance, int index )
   {
      this.distance = distance;
      this.index = index;
   }
}

class MyGame
{
   Vector3[] positions;
   Vector3 myObject;
   Vector3[] four = new Vector3[4];

   List<Distance> distanceList = new List<Distance>();

   void Foo()
   {
      for( int i = 0; i < positions.Length; i++ )
      {
         // get all the distances
         float distance = Vector3.Distance( positions[i], myObject );
         // store the distance with the index of the position
         distanceList.Add( new Distance( distance, i ) );
      }

      // sort the distances
      distanceList.Sort( delegate (Distance t1, Distance t2) { return (t1.distance.CompareTo(t2.distance)); } );

      for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
      {
         // get the first four sorted distances
         int idx = distanceList[i].index;
         // use the stored index
         four[i] = positions[idx];
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Describe, what your code should to do, what result do you expect or what is your question?

Comment: this code should solve the question asked by UareBugged

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake... Anyway, please, cut a bit your code and make a description..

Comment: @Phoenix no problem :) there are already a few comments in the code. what line do you want me to explain?

Comment: Here is some advice: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer  It's great when answer has not only code and comments in it, but some explanations what do you do and what for..

Comment: i have edited it. now it should be completely clear to anyone who reads the original question.

Comment: @Phoenix no problem :) if there is anything else i can do, let me know!